# What are some things worth less than $100 buying which can save you money in the longer run?

Tags: investing

What are the best $100 worth of things one can buy that can in a long run provide a value much more than $100?

Comment: This would be much better suited to Ask Reddit.

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff: I agree but the quality of answers of StackExchange is much better than Reddit.

Comment: $100 dollars worth of beer from the grocery could save you hundreds compared to drinking in upscale bars.

Comment: I've saved thousands of dollars over the past decade by dropping cable and subscribing to Netflix.  I don't even miss the sports.

Answer (score 1):

This seems heavily opinion based but I think there are some generic answers.

- A screwdriver set and wrench. I used both today to fix my daughter's bike after she crashed.
- Thread and needle.
- A utility knife and chef's knife. These cover 90+% of cutting tasks in the kitchen. Saves one hundreds of dollars a month if they can cook from scratch.
- An Amazon Kindle. Or a library pass.